# dataframe groupby transform: conditional sum based on current row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, transform

I have a dataframe that lists quantities by article, shop and size: several million rows.

The task is:
If article A with size S has a non-nan quantity in shop P, then sum up *all* the sizes of article A in shop P. Show the sum in a new column, beside the quantity of size S. If the row shows NaN units, do not sum up the sizes.
To avoid iterating over the rows, I think it should be possible to use groupby-transform-lambda. But how can I restrict the conditional lambda sum to aggregate the units of all sizes just for the shop and article shown in the *current* row? Something like:

```
    df["Result"] = df.groupby(["article", "size"])["units"].transform(lambda x: (x=="all 
                      sizes, but just for the article and shop of the current row").sum())
```

dataframe:

```
   dict = {"article":("A","A","A","A", "A", "A","A"),
           "shop":("x","x","y","y",    "z","z","z"),
           "size":("M","L","M","L",    "M","L","S"),
           "units":(1,2,np.nan,4,      np.nan,6,7)}
   df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

If an article/size pair has non-nan units in shop P, then sum up ALL the sizes of the article in shop P.

```
   df["Result"] = [1+2, 1+2, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 6+7, 6+7]
```

Examples:
(1) Article A has 2 sizes in shop x, both with non-nan units, so show their sum in both size rows.
(2) In shop z, article A has sizes L and S with valid units, but size M with NaN. Thus, show the sum of L and S in both size rows - whereas size M in shop z gets NaN.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the simple answer:

```
    df["Result_"] = np.where(np.isnan(df["units"]), np.nan, df.groupby(["article", "shop"])["units"].transform("sum"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).